# After authentication using Auth0, problems occur when reloading

Tags: auth0, vercel

I am working on a website that is deployed in Vercel.
The problem is happening both on localhost launched from the Vercel CLI and in the production environment.

After a Google social login with Auth0, a handleRedirectCallback is called from the string stored in the URL parameter and the session information is stored in a cookie.
After login, when the page is reloaded, the rendering of the screen stops in the middle of the page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHqlt.png)

```
async function checkAuthState() {
  console.log('checkAuthState');
  const shouldParseResult = window.location.search.includes("code=") &&  window.location.search.includes("state=");
  let user;
  if(shouldParseResult){
    await auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
    user = await getUser(auth0Client);
    console.log('user', user);
  }
  return user;
}
```

localhost:3000/,[vercel's production environment URL] is set for Allowed Callback URLs, Allowed Logout URLs, Allowed Web Origins, and Allowed Origin (CORS) in Auth0.

If handleRedirectCallback is not executed and nothing is added to the cookie, it can be reloaded successfully after login.

In other words, it works fine if nothing is stored in the cookie.

It is my opinion that you are violating CROS policy, but I don't believe that the Auth0 setting is wrong.
Because I can log in itself.